# Compile FFTW with pgcc, undefined reference

Tags: c, fftw, pgi, pgcc

For other software I need fftw-2.1.5 with `--enable-mpi --enable-type-prefix --enable-float` installed. It should be compiled with `pgcc`

PGCC, etc. are installed under the `/home` directory. For this post I have shortend it with `path-to`.

I do:

```
./configure --prefix=/path-to/fftw --enable-mpi --enable-type-prefix --enable-float CC=path-to/pgcc CXX=path-to/pgc++ F77=path-to/pgf77 FC=path-to/pgfortran

make`
```

`./configure` finishes successful, during `make` I get this error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../fftw/.libs/libsfftw.a(malloc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against .rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: ../fftw/.libs/libsfftw.a(putils.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against .rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: ../fftw/.libs/libsfftw.a(twiddle.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against .data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried to recompile with the `-fPIC` flag:

```
make clean
make CFLAGS="-fPIC"
```

Then I get:

```
../fftw/.libs/libsfftw.a(twiddle.o): In function `fftw_compute_twiddle':
/home/daniel/fftw-test/fftw-2.1.5/fftw/./twiddle.c:92: undefined reference to `__fd_sincos_1'
/home/daniel/fftw-test/fftw-2.1.5/fftw/./twiddle.c:126: undefined reference to `__fd_sincos_1'
../fftw/.libs/libsfftw.a(twiddle.o): In function `fftw_compute_rader_twiddle':
/home/daniel/fftw-test/fftw-2.1.5/fftw/./twiddle.c:65: undefined reference to `__fd_sincos_1'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've now tried to find a solution to why this happens for hours but I cannot figure it out.

When I configure it to use the gcc compiler (system default) everything works perfectly:

```
./configure --prefix=/fftw --enable-mpi --enable-type-prefix --enable-float
make
make install
```

EDIT, more information:

- The program for which I need fftw, needs pgcc. I though it would be best if I compile everything with it as it was recommended on some forum sites.
- In twiddle.c there is not a single mention of `__fd_sincos_1`. For example line 92 is simply
  `for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {`
- When I drop the `--enable-type-prefix` nothing changes. Still the same error.

Comment: "*It should be compiled with pgcc*" should it? Who says so?

Comment: And also it would be interesting to see the code in `twiddle.c` which seems to be using those "undefined symbols".

Comment: Out of the blue: What happens if you drop `--enable-type-prefix` from the pgCC command line?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added some information at the end of the post.

Comment: Make a clean rebuild *without* any optimisation enabled and then recheck the source references the linker issues within it's warnings.

Comment: The second error is most likely because the libtool is old and doesn't know to add "-lpgm" to the link.  Try using CFLAGS="-O3 -fPIC -lpgm".